# Can we automatically delete images on a device with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

My Flutter app will be used to capture image then save to device. I want to remove all images in my device at a preset time. Is there a way to do that?

I think it not because if an app can delete all the images in device so it will not safe to use that app but I still hope it have because it needs for my app.

Comment: Things are changing with the recent releases of Android. Access to file system is not going to be same. but you are going to save the captured image in a folder where you have write access, there you can delete all the pictures without a problem

Comment: Thanks you sir. it's a good way to deal with that @VarunMalhotra

Comment: Should I post this as an answer so that you can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are changing with the recent releases of Android. Access to file system is not going to be same. but you are going to save the captured image in a folder where you have write access, there you can delete all the pictures without a problem